# How to Make Status bar widget clickable and read only openerp 7.0

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, erp

This is my Form View

```
 <form string="Meeting Information" version="7.0" >
                <header>
                    <field name="status" widget="statusbar"  clickable="1" />
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group string="Details">
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="pro_date"/>
                            <field name="type"/>
                        </group>
                        <group string="More Details">
                            <field name="notes"/>
                            <field name="pro_assign_to"/>
                            <field name="user_assign"/>
                        </group>
                    </group> 
                </sheet>
            </form>
```

i want to make form readonly when the status bar item **done** is clicked

the selection field **status**

```
'status':fields.selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ],'Type', ),
```

pls help..

Answer (score 1):

In your Model fields definition you need to add this piece of code to make field readonly no certain state :

```
    'name': fields.char('Order Reference', size=64, required=True,
        readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]]}, select=True),
```

As you see `readonly=True` will make your field readolny forever but `, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]]}` this piece of code will add behavior that field will be readonly=False on certain condition.

Here instead of `readonly` you can also use the  `required` or `invisible` and you can use multiple `domain` conditoin also to make it more complex.

Thanks